# Gnome desktop icons turn gigantic

Tags: gnome, desktop-icons

My GNOME desktop icons suddenly turn into enormous large (see screenshot) for unknown reason.
[image]

Any idea to turn it back to normal?
I am using Ubuntu 17.10.